# Trouble installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: boot, server, system-installation

I am really new to installing Ubuntu and don't have much experience with it. I just built my computer and used Rufus to burn the Ubuntu Server 18.04 to a USB flash drive. When I turn on the computer I get to the boot screen asking what I want to do. I click Install Ubuntu Server. Immediately after, I get error messages in the top left.

```
[0.751233] AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf computer
[0.882256] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[0.882279] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[0.882472] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[0.882665] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

Specs:

- CPU: Ryzen 3 2200g
- RAM: G.Skill 16GB (2 x 8GB) Aegis DDR4
- mobo: MSI Performance Gaming AMD Ryzen Mini-ITX (B450I Gaming Plus AC)
- SSD: Kingston Digital SUV500M8/120G 120GB SSDNOW UV500 M.2
- HDD: 4TB Seagate Iron Wolf

Comment: [How to install ubuntu in UEFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927924/how-to-install-ubuntu-in-uefi-mode) .....is a previously asked question that may provide some answers.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which installer you attempted to use. The `subiquity` 'live' installer is still a work-in-progress, thus why the 'di' installer is still available - which did you download & try to install with?   *If it's a gaming desktop, it maybe simpler to install desktop (which will likely cope with desktop hardware esp. graphics  unless you system can limit itself to basic video like a server has) then uninstall what you don't want*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install ubuntu in UEFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927924/how-to-install-ubuntu-in-uefi-mode)