# Dual Boot on Separate Drives: Grub Customizer can't see Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows

I've searched for similar questions but I can't find something. I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20 on my PC. They are installed on different drives : Win10 in my SSD, and Ubuntu in another Hard Disk. I want to change the boot order in the grub menu (I just want the cursor on the grub menu to first point at Windows instead of Ubuntu). However when I use Grub Customizer to change the default boot order, [I can't see Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziFbB.png). But I can see it with `efibootmgr`. However when I change the boot order with it and put Windows in first choice, the Grub Menu doesnt show anymore and directly boots into Win10 instead (I think that this is normal). **This is not what I want**. I just want to make sure that the default option on the grub menu if I don't touch my keyboard, is Win10.

When I installed Ubuntu I chose "Something Else" but I'm not really sure where I put the MBR (I think it was in the SSD). I don't really need to use Grub Customizer in particular, I just want to change my Grub Menu.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For dual-boot to work you need to make sure both Ubuntu and Windows are installed in either `UEFI` for `BIOS/Legacy` mode.

Comment: In the GRUB Menu, Windows option is called "Windows (UEFI)", my ubuntu is 64-bit, CSM is diabled, as well as Fast Startup and Hibernate on Windows, I used Rufus to create the installation image, and in my ubuntu system files there's a "something.efi" file. According to https://askubuntu.com/questions/927924/how-to-install-ubuntu-in-uefi-mode, it is likely that both of my OS's are in UEFI mode. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Okay here is the link :https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4MTSqdXbdV/

Comment: After 2 days of trying to solve the issue, I still haven't found something.