# Unable to do normal boot: Have to manually boot from SATA boot from BIOS

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

I was trying to reinstall ubuntu 18.04 and ended up installing it both on my 1 TB and 2TB harddisk. My system is not booting up now unless I go to BIOS and select SATA boot drive. There is no longer any efi boot option which earlier was present.

How do I fix this? Also how do I make sure that there is only one ubuntu installation and the other one is deleted? I am not very good at jargon of ubuntu so please pardon the ignorance.

Comment: Can you disconnect the drive you do not want the OS installed on, do a complete reinstallation, reconnect the disconnected storage device, then format the sucker so it’s empty? It’s a pain in the bum, but a very simple way to ensure expected results 

Comment: Can't I simply boot from one harddisk and format the another? I am already booted from one hard disk. Also why do I have to go to BIOS to boot everytime? Why is it not normally booting?

Comment: Reformat the one you don't want by using a live USB in GParted.

Comment: @matigo it is not possible at the moment to physically disconnect the harddrive.

Comment: When you reinstalled It sounds like you did it in legacy mode and not UEFI mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/927924/how-to-install-ubuntu-in-uefi-mode#928101

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Boot into the Live Installation USB 
**Step 2:** Click on Try Ubuntu, Instead of Install Ubuntu
**Step 3:** Press the Windows Key and start Typing GParted(It will start searching for Gparted)
**Step 4:** Open GParted
From here, I can Link a guide for you.
[How to format a drive](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-format-usb)\

Follow the Third Method of the article